# How can I show "NO RESULTS" in kendo Mobile ListView

Tags: listview, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have this new Kendo ListView starting with endless scrolling, the thing is that when the list returns NULL, an error appears in the console. NULL IS NOT AN OBJECT the thing is that with other lists i have the loader appears and doesn't stop loading and doesn't let you do anything. The best solution would be to show no results but I don't have a way of showing the total results. datasource.total() always shows 0. I really don't have anymore ideas on how to do this. I would appreciate some help. I will post my code. Sorry my bad english.

```
function funcion() {
var dataSource_seguidores_articulos = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
        read:  {
            url: "xxxxxxxx",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {token: xxx, motivo: x}
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "results",
        total: "total"
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true
});

$("#listview").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: dataSource_seguidores_articulos,
    template: $("#template").text(),
    endlessScroll: true
});
```

}

The best idea, for the error not to show and create conflicts, would be to do something like:

if(datasource.total() === 0)
{
    NO RESULTS
}
else
{
    CODE FOR LISTVIEW
}

PHP AJAX URL API RETURNS THIS

```
jQuery1910311110318871215_1397568743279(({ "results":null, "total": 1})
```

but datasource total always shows 0. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems odd that the server returns `null` results, but indicates there is `1` record. If possible, have the server return an empty array instead of `null`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a less intrusive solution and are OK with a generic message for all instances, you can use CSS to deal with this.

```
[data-role="listview"]:empty::after {
    content: 'No records to show';
}
```

Personally I like this because I don't have to pass through the ID of elements that are empty, or target every element with JS. It also doesn't change the DOM, which may prevent Kendo from operating correctly. This solution will update fine when a record becomes available.

Update: There are issues in IE11 with this solution. The text will appear in some populated lists, and disappear as soon as the screen paints because of a mouse move

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled this in the past is to MVVM bind the visibility of my list and a "no results" message to the count of the items. Something like:

```
<div data-bind="visible: hasData">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: data" data-template="list-template"></ul>
</div>
<div data-bind="invisible: hasData">
    <span>No Records.</span>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
var ds = kendo.DataSource({...});

ds.bind("change", function () {
    vm.set("hasData", ds.total() > 0);
});

var vm = kendo.observable({
    hasData: false,
    data: ds
});
```

Comment: and if `DataSource.total()` doesn't seem to be working, try `DataSource.view().length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually replace the kendo listview content.  I know that, for example, kendo grid does not have an empty-data template so in the databound event I check the table contents of tbody and go from there. In your particular case, you may need to test how many 'li' tag markup items there are in ul.km-listview. If the length is zero, you may insert your own formatted li item that display "No Items Available":

```
<li class="km-group-container">
    <div class="km-group-title">
        <div class="km-text">No Items Available</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="km-list">
        <li data-icon="toprated">
            <a class="km-listview-link" data-role="listview-link">
                <span class="km-icon km-toprated"></span>Please try again.</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Good luck

**Update**
Try this in your onGridDatabound event:

```
var listElement = $("#yourlistname li");
if (listElement.size() == 0) {
     $("#yourlistname").append("the empty html above");
}
```

Comment: The thing is that is not working. Length always brings undefined or a number and undefined doesn't let you do anything and total always brings 0

Comment: Can you please post how to implement this in Angular Kendo.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var listViewModel = kendo.observable({
                listData: ListModel
            });
            listViewModel.bind('change', function (e) {
                if (e.items.length > 0) {
    refreshList();
                } else {
                     $('#noresult-alert').data('kendoMobileModalView').open();
                }
            });
    div-#noresult-alert is a kendoui mobile mdalview may have your custom message.
Note:using modalview may open once ata a time and no need of handle any stoppropagation here since fwk doesn't provide it internally.
```